# Error: ‘MatrixExponential’ is not a member of ‘Eigen’

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I am using unsupported part of the Eigen library to compute the matrix exponential. I am getting the error: ‘MatrixExponential’ is not a member of ‘Eigen’. I am using the CMake to make build files for my project. Other supported functions for Eigen work within my project.

```
#include "unsupported/Eigen/src/MatrixFunctions/MatrixExponential.h"
...
Eigen::Matrix3f Ak;
    Ak<< 1, 2, 3,
         4, 5, 6,
         7, 8, 9;
    std::cout<<Eigen::MatrixExponential(Ak).compute();
```

and CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-ffast-math")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
add_executable(project src/main.cpp src/css2dss.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project Eigen3::Eigen)
```

I tried brute forcing with

```
#include "../../repos/eigen/unsupported/Eigen/src/MatrixFunctions/MatrixExponential.h"
```

but I get the error

```
#error "Please include unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions instead of including headers inside the src directory directly."
```

but when I try

```
#include "unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions"
```

is still get the initial error.

Comment: *I am using the CMake* Don't you think this information is not very useful, if CMakeLists.txt is not shown?

Comment: Did you try `Ak.exp()` as documented here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html#matrixbase_exp -- if that does not work, post a [mre] of your failing code.

Comment: Jupp, MatrixExponential isn't a class. If it is, please post the version of Eigen that you use. That stuff about cmake is a red herring. Just use ```matrix.exp()```